# Creating a Highly Customized Header and Footer F/ Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hopefully this helps anyone who struggled with the restrictive header-footer options in Excel. Below is a routine that I am using to create a highly customized header and footer for excel. I found a routine on a forum to save cells to an image http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=45682.

I have a hidden sheet for that purpose "Header and Footer Developer". There is a set of cells that I have graphics such as company logos, and text that define the header and footer. The routines work flawlessly for me. ***My question: I am looking to improve upon is the quality of the resulted image.*** It is not bad but definitely could be better.

Regards,

Mahmoud

```
Sub PrintFomatter()
Dim HeaderTitle As String
Dim PrintSheet As String
Dim AddiTioNal_InFo_Check As Boolean

If ActiveSheet.Name Like "*PRINT*" Then Exit Sub
Call miscellaneous.Initializer


'Gets the header title
Select Case True
    Case ActiveSheet.Name Like "*Bill*"
        HeaderTitle = "Bill of Materials"
        PrintSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
End Select

'Informs the user of the next action
MsgBox ("This tool generates a printer-friendly version of " & HeaderTitle & " Sheet." & vbNewLine & _
        "Do Not use this sheet for editing inputs. The Sheet would automatically be DELETED after printing."), vbInformation

'Generates the Header/Footer Banner
Call HeaderFooterDeveloper.HeaderFooter(HeaderTitle, AddiTioNal_InFo_Check)

'Formats Sheet
Call miscellaneous.PrintSheetDeveloper(HeaderTitle, PrintSheet, AddiTioNal_InFo_Check)



Dim myPassword As String
'myPassword = "password"
For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name Like "*PRINT*" Then
    Else
        WS.Protect 'Password:=myPassword
    End If
Next WS
    With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .StatusBar = False
End With

End Sub
Sub HeaderFooter(Header As String, AddiTioNal_InFo_Check As Boolean)

Dim i As Long ' i: Counter
Dim AddiTioNal_InFo As String
Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("F6").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("J6").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

'Gets additional info is USED by user
AddiTioNal_InFo = BOM.Cells(BOM.Range("ToolMatNum").Row - 1, BOM.Range("ToolMatNum").Column)

'Check is user added additonal info
If Not AddiTioNal_InFo = "" And Not AddiTioNal_InFo = "-" And Not AddiTioNal_InFo = "N/A" And Not AddiTioNal_InFo = "n/a" And _
        Not AddiTioNal_InFo = " " And Not AddiTioNal_InFo = "NA" And Not AddiTioNal_InFo = "na" Then AddiTioNal_InFo_Check = True


Select Case True
    Case ActiveSheet.Name = BOM.Name
        Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("AB5") = "Checked By:"
        Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("AB6") = "Approved By:"
        Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("AC5") = BOM.Range("Checker").Value
        Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("AC6") = BOM.Range("Approver").Value
        Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("AE6") = "Date:"
        Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("AF5") = BOM.Cells(Range("Checker").Row, Range("Checker").Column + 2).Value
        Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("AF6") = BOM.Cells(Range("Approver").Row, Range("Approver").Column + 2).Value
End Select


Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("A2") = Header & ": " & BOM.Range("D1")

'Calls SAVE_PICTURE to save Header and Footer banner
For i = 0 To 1
    Select Case True
        Case i = 0 'First Page Header Generator
            Select Case True
                Case Is = AddiTioNal_InFo_Check = False
                    Set HeadFoot = Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("A1:AF6")
                Case AddiTioNal_InFo_Check = True
                    Set HeadFoot = Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("A1:AF7")
            End Select

            HeaderFileName = "FirstHeaderFileFor_Bill of Materials.png"
            SAVE_PICTURE   'Calls routine to save picture

        Case i = 1 'Footer Generator
            Set HeadFoot = Worksheets("Header_Footer_Developer").Range("A33:AF35")
            HeaderFileName = "FooterFileFor_Bill of Materials.png"
            SAVE_PICTURE   'Calls routine to save picture
    End Select
Next i

End Sub
'=============================================================================
'- COPY PICTURES FROM A WORKSHEET TO .BMP FILES
'- VERSION 2 : uses code to save file instead of SendKeys/MS Paint
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'- Thanks to the code attributed to JAAFAR of MrExcel forum (with no messages present now)
'- Ref : http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=45682
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'- Picks up Embedded objects (OLEObjects) and Pictures (Picture objects)
'=============================================================================
'- *** AMEND THESE CONST VALUES AND RUN THE MACRO FROM THE SHEET
Const BitmapFileName As String = "XLpicture" 'file name without "_00x.bmp"
Const MyPictureFolder As String = "C:\Users\marzmah\Videos\Cylinder Fixture __ Prototype Cost2_files" ' target folder for files
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'- 1. Copies all pictures from sheet.
'- 2. Gets next file name in the series (filenames format like "xxx_001.bmp")
'- 3. Saves file in target folder.
'- Brian Baulsom November 2008
'=============================================================================
'- VERSION 1 : Userform Screen copy July 2008 using SendKeys/MS Paint
'- Save Userform as BMP
'=============================================================================
'- DECLARATIONS & VARIABLES TO SAVE PICTURE FILE FROM CLIPBOARD
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" _
    (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'- IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
Data1 As Long
Data2 As Integer
Data3 As Integer
Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type
'-store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc
Size As Long
Type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4
Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID
Dim uPicinfo As uPicDesc
Dim IPic As IPicture
Dim hPtr As Long
'=============================================================================
'- WORKSHEET/PICTURE VARIABLES
Dim HeadFoot As Range
Dim MyPicture As Object        ' PICTURES IN SHEET
Dim PictureCount As Integer
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'- BITMAP FILE : FULL PATH & FILE NAME
Dim HeaderFileName As String
Dim FullFileName As String '= MyPictureFolder & HeaderFileName & "_00x.bmp"
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'- GET NEXT FILE NAME (Uses FileSystemObject)
Dim fso As Object
Dim FileNumber As Integer
Dim LastFileNumber As Integer
'-- end of declarations ------------------------------------------------------

'- SUBROUTINE : SAVE PICTURE FROM CLIPBOARD AS A BITMAP FILE (JAAFAR'S CODE)
'- Called from main routine
'=============================================================================
Private Sub SAVE_PICTURE()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select  ' focus from button or picture to sheet
    LastFileNumber = 0              ' counter
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' FOR NEXTFILENAME

    FullFileName = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\" & HeaderFileName

    'Sheet2.Range ("A1:AL5")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    HeadFoot.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap       ' MyPicture.Copy
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------
    OpenClipboard 0
    hPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP)
    CloseClipboard

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
     'Create the interface GUID for the picture
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
     '  Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
    With uPicinfo

        .Size = Len(uPicinfo) ' Length of structure.
        .Type = PICTYPE_BITMAP ' Type of Picture
        .hPic = hPtr ' Handle to image.
        .hPal = 0 ' Handle to palette (if bitmap).
    End With
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
     'Create the Picture Object
    OleCreatePictureIndirect uPicinfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
     'Save Picture
    stdole.SavePicture IPic, FullFileName
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
     'fix the clipboard (it seems to go messed up)
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Sub



Sub PrintSheetDeveloper(HeaderTitle As String, PrintSheet As String, AddiTioNal_InFo_Check As Boolean) 'This Routine Develops a Printer-Friendly WorkSheet.

Dim PrintSheetTitle As String
Dim nm As Name, WS As Worksheet
Dim LastUsedRow(1 To 4) As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long, LastCol As Long, i As Long, LastRow As Long, LastRowRng As Range, MergeRng(1 To 2) As Range
Dim DPI_SettingFactor As Double, DPI_Setting As String
PrintSheetTitle = "PRINT SHEET--" & HeaderTitle

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name Like "*PRINT*" Then WS.Delete
Next WS
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

'Creats A Copy of Active Spreadsheet
Worksheets(PrintSheet).Copy before:=BOM

'Gets Screen DPI Settings to Adjust Print Options Accordingly
DPI_Setting = GetDpi()
If DPI_Setting Like "96" Then
    DPI_SettingFactor = 0.97385
Else
    DPI_SettingFactor = 1
End If


'Changes Name of ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = PrintSheetTitle

'Changes Sheet Tab color to grey
Worksheets(PrintSheetTitle).Tab.ColorIndex = xlNone

ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview 'xlPageLayoutView

Select Case True
    'Formats Bill of Materials Sheet
        Case HeaderTitle = "Bill of Materials"
            FirstRow = BOM.Range("ItemNo_BOM").Row
            LastCol = BOM.Range("Comment_BOM").Column
        'Changes the color of rows (Alternating Grey and White rows)
            For i = FirstRow + 1 To 150 Step 2
                Worksheets(PrintSheetTitle).Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, LastCol)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                Worksheets(PrintSheetTitle).Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, LastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(228, 228, 228)
            Next i
            Worksheets(PrintSheetTitle).Range(Cells(151, 1), Cells(151, LastCol)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            'Hides existing header on sheet (will be replaced by header banner)
            Worksheets(PrintSheetTitle).Rows("1:4").Hidden = True

            'Gets last row from specific columns
            LastUsedRow(1) = BOM.Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            LastUsedRow(2) = BOM.Columns("C").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            LastUsedRow(3) = BOM.Columns("E").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            LastUsedRow(4) = WorksheetFunction.Max(LastUsedRow(1), LastUsedRow(2), LastUsedRow(3))
End Select

'Adjust the Print Setup for Bill of Materials
With Worksheets(PrintSheetTitle).PageSetup
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = False
    Select Case True
    'FORMATS BoM SHEET
        Case HeaderTitle = "Bill of Materials"
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\FirstHeaderFileFor_Bill of Materials.png"
            .LeftHeader = "&G"
            .LeftHeaderPicture.LockAspectRatio = True
            .CenterFooterPicture.Filename = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\FooterFileFor_Bill of Materials.png"
            .CenterFooter = "&G"
            .LeftHeaderPicture.Width = Application.InchesToPoints(9.5 * DPI_SettingFactor)
            .CenterFooterPicture.Width = Application.InchesToPoints(9.6 * DPI_SettingFactor)
            'Checks if there is additional info - and accounts for additional header margin
            Select Case True
                Case AddiTioNal_InFo_Check = False
                    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.1)
                Case AddiTioNal_InFo_Check = True
                    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.24)
            End Select
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.65)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .PrintQuality = 600
            .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .CenterFooterPicture.LockAspectRatio = True
            .LeftFooter = "&" & Chr(34) & "Arial, regular" & Chr(34) & "&7" & "&B Print Date: &B &D " & "    " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) '& Chr(13) 'vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            .RightFooter = "&" & Chr(34) & "Arial &8" & Chr(34) & "&7" & "Page &P of &N " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) '& Chr(13)
            .PrintArea = Range(Cells(FirstRow - 1, 1), Cells(LastUsedRow(4), LastCol)).Address
    End Select
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I fail to see a clear question and this is most definitely **not** a [mcve].

Comment: The routines work flawlessly for me, the only thing that I would like to improve upon is the quality of the resulted image. It is not bad but definitely could be better. 

That is my question. I want to improve upon the quality of the image.

Comment: *The routines work flawlessly for me, the only thing that I would like to improve upon* - Perhaps question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)